# Deleting the lowest CARD# for customers with more than one CARD# of that type

Tags: sql, sql-delete, min

I have a customer table and I need to delete the lowest card number for a specific card number for customers who have more than one card number of that type stored. I can write a select query for it but when I try turn it into a delete it doesn't work.

- |`CustomerID` | `Card#`  |`Card Type`|`TableID` |
- |      1      | 123456   | AA        | 789      |
- |      1      | 234567   | AA        | 999      |
- |      1      | 98989881 | BC        | 223      |
- |      2      | 678945   | AA        | 123      |
- |      2      | 987536   | AA        | 689      |
- |      2      | 99978821 | BC        | 334      |

Expecting that there will only be one Card# for each customer for the card type AA. It should not touch any other card type #s.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.